# Não consigo carregar uma View após chamada $.post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Estou passando o parâmetro abaixo (cliente), de uma função jQuery para uma *Action*, através do comando `$.post` (como demonstrado abaixo).

O parâmetro chega corretamente na minha *action*, porém não consigo retornar para a *View* que eu desejo. Provavelmente, o `$.post` está esperando esse retorno, por isso a *View* não é carregada.

Alguém sabe se há uma maneira de desativar esse retorno ao `$.post`, ou alguma outra sugestão para que eu possa carregar a minha *View*?

A funcao jQuery:

```
function CriarCliente() {
    var cliente =
    {
        CLIENTE_NOME: $('#CRIARCLIENTE_NOME').val().trim().toUpperCase(),
        CLIENTE_RG: $('#CRIARCLIENTE_RG').val().trim()
    }

    var urlDestino = "/CadastroPessoa/Cliente/CriarCliente";

    $.post(urlDestino, { cliente: cliente }) 
}
```

O *Controller*:

```
public ActionResult CriarCliente(ClienteEnt cliente)
{
   .........CÓDIGO.....

   return View("ListarCliente", cliente);
}
```

No caso, não consigo carregar a *View*.

Obrigado a todos.

Answer (score 1):

Requisições Ajax não fazem redirecionamento automaticamente. E sua função javascript não está recebendo o retorno da action.

**Se sua intenção for redirecionar o usuário para outra página.** Você deverá alterar sua função JavaScript para algo do tipo:

```
function CriarCliente(){
    var cliente =
    {
        CLIENTE_NOME: $('#CRIARCLIENTE_NOME').val().trim().toUpperCase(),
        CLIENTE_RG: $('#CRIARCLIENTE_RG').val().trim()
    }

    var urlDestino = "/CadastroPessoa/Cliente/CriarCliente";

    $.post(urlDestino, { cliente: cliente }, function(data){
        //Se retorno OK
        window.location.replace(data.url);
    }).fail(function(){
        alert("erro.");
    });
}
```

E o seu controller para:

```
public ActionResult CriarCliente(ClienteEnt cliente)
{
   .........CÓDIGO.....
    if(Request.IsAjaxResquest()) // Se for usa requisição Ajax retorno a url para redirecionamento.
        return Json(new {url = "/Controller/Action/"});

    //Senão. Retorno a View Cliente.
    return View("ListarCliente", cliente);
}
```

**Se sua intenção for apenas exibir o conteúdo da view em algum lugar da página atual.** Você deverá alterar sua função JavaScript para algo do tipo:

```
function CriarCliente(){
    var cliente =
    {
        CLIENTE_NOME: $('#CRIARCLIENTE_NOME').val().trim().toUpperCase(),
        CLIENTE_RG: $('#CRIARCLIENTE_RG').val().trim()
    }

    var urlDestino = "/CadastroPessoa/Cliente/CriarCliente";

    $.post(urlDestino, { cliente: cliente }, function(data){
        //Se retorno OK
        $("#container").html(data);
    }).fail(function(){
        alert("erro.");
    });
}
```

E o seu controller continua como estava.